# Is there an MVC way of doing ASCX?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-controls, ascx

Are ASCXs still used in ASP.NET MVC or should we be using something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can still use .ascx.  They are often referred to as partial views.

Answer (score 3):

You bet, I typically use an ascx to render a partial view for some type of ajax functionality. Although, as Jeffrey Palermo [points out](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-and-the-templated-partial-view-death-to-ascx/) they don't add much value beyond the extension being a direct inclination that your are working with a partial view.

Answer (score 3):

The great thing about them is that in your controller you can then use

```
return PartialView("MyPartialView", items);
```

This works great in a jQuery call when you are only interested in changing the contents of particular part of the page and not the whole page.